# jquery animation in css-transformed iframe bug in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, jquery-animate, rendering, css-transforms

I found out strange behavior in chrome when displaying animated page in iframe that has been scaled down with css-transforms.

Tested using:

- chrome 39.0.2171.99 m
- firefox 35.0
- iexplore 11

  ```
  <!-- animation.html -->
  <html>
      <head>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
          <script>
              $( function(){
                  $( '#bar' )
                      .on( 'startAnim', function(){
                          $( this )
                              .css( 'width', '0%' )
                              .animate( { width: '100%' }, 15000, function(){ $( this ).trigger( 'startAnim' ); } )
                          ;
                      } )
                      .trigger( 'startAnim' )
                  ;
              } );
          </script>
          <style>
              #bar{
                  height            : 100%;
                  position          : absolute;
                  left              : 0;
                  top               : 0;
                  width             : 0%;
                  background-color  : red;
              }
          </style>
      </head>
      <body>
          <div id="bar"></div>
      </body>
  </html>

  <!-- test.html -->
  <html>
      <head>
          <style>
              iframe{
                  width             : 1920px;
                  height            : 1080px;
                  -webkit-transform : scale(0.25);
                  -moz-transform    : scale(0.25);
                  -ms-transform     : scale(0.25);
                  -o-transform      : scale(0.25);
                  transform         : scale(0.25);
              }
          </style>
      </head>
      <body>
          <iframe src="animation.html"></iframe>
      </body>
  </html>
  ```

Instead of filling the body of the iframed document with red div, it renders  like barcode!

[SCREENSHOT](http://i60.tinypic.com/bgb814.png)